# Wifi Broadcast android inside android intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-wifi

I'm learning android and I'm stuck here:

The app which I'm writing scans for Wifi signals in background periodically. I am using android intent service for the same. The problem is, application never executes **onReceive()** method of BroadCastReceiver

Intent Code:

```
public class BackgroundIntent extends IntentService {

    // Default Constructor
    public BackgroundIntent() {
        super("BackgroundIntent");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    WifiManager mainWifi;
    BroadcastReceiver receiverWifi;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Get mainWifi
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
            mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        doInback();

    }

    // Basically a thread which calls itself after 5000milli sec
    public void doInback() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mainWifi.startScan();
                Log.i("Inside ", "doInBack");

                // Call itself CODE GOES HERE :D
                doInback();
            }
        }, 5000);

    }

    public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            // CODE NEVER GOES HERE :(

            List<ScanResult> wifiList;
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();

            Log.i("Inside receiver", "yes");

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity code which invokes android intent service

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView texty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Intent is called here
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundIntent.class);
        startService(myIntent);

        texty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

Any idea what may be the cause? Is this wrong way to implement background wifi signal scan.
The same when I implement in Main Activity runs fine, so I'm guessing AndroidManifest.xml is correctly written..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was with the functions which I was using.

I was using *onHandleIntent(intent)* which is the wrong function. Right one is **onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)** for service.

My bad sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I might've misinterpreted your goal here, If your just wondering why your onReceive() isn't firing, your activity has to register the receiver.  Something like the following:

```
receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
doInback();
```

[Check out this link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, I'm already using broadcast receiver for Wifireceiver

Comment: Tried that, Still no result :(

It enters _doInback()_ but fails to invoke _onReceive()_

Comment: That's the best you can do, onReceive() won't execute immediately because its still probably scanning.  Scanning can take between 1 second to 1 hour, best you can do is set-up a receiver & cross your fingers :)

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply!

Is this delay for scanning because of using this inside Android Intent? It works perfectly fine when inside Activity..
If this is the case, I'll mark this as resolved

Comment: Tried that as well, no difference..
Also I checked it in logs, _doInback()_ function is invoked after 5seconds as intended. Which means there is no delay in wifi-scanning..

I'll keep this question open for a day more before resolving it. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is while scanning first, its taking longer than 5 seconds .. but since another call to startScan() takes place by then, the previous startScan() never had the chance to broadcast the results.. with all this you can actually just start scan from you main thread, or simply from the onCreate() , i've updated with a link

Comment: Again I don't think scanning is the problem because I increased the delay to 15sec, still the same result.. I would really like intent to handle the scanning because by definition, doing this in Intent fits :)

Comment: have you checked if startScan() is returning true, boolean success = false;
while(success == false){
  success = mainWifi.startScan();
}

Comment: yep it returns true. I also rebooted phone, and checked it on other phones too.
Trust me, I really wish that my code is wrong somewhere, because this is leading me nowhere :D

Comment: that is odd, only other peculiarity I see is that on the first doInback() invocation, a startScan() wouldn't immediately happen, but would happen 5 seconds later which might be what you desire

Comment: I tried the same method (i.e. dispatching threads of _doInback()_ ) in Activity, and it works perfectly fine..

Comment: the only difference there is that the handler you have declared in IntentService is not the main thread, whereas, dispatching runnables in your Activity's handler runs on the main thread.. you are registeringReceiver in your activity correct? Guess the problem could just be that you need to startScan() on the main ui thread

Comment: May be this is a stupid question, but why should startScan() work in main ui thread and not in Intent Service? Receiver is registered inside Intent P.S. Haven't checked invoking startScan() in main ui thread..